# How to show method description?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using the newest pyCharm version. When I type the following:

```
myList =  [1, 2, "test"]
x = myList.
```

the different available function for the myList object popup. But there is no description of the methods available.

How can I get pyCharm showing me the method descriptions (what the method does, the arguments etc.)?

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2010/07/autopopup-documentation-feature/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonsharpe suggests in the comment, you need to enable the `autopopup documentation` setting. 
You can find it following this path:

```
Settings->Editor->General->Code Completion
```

set the tick on, and if you want set up also the ms. 
This value is the delay time to open it.

Now, when you invoke the functionality which show you all possible methods (for me is Ctrl + Space) also the relative doc is showed.

Let me know.